# Jquery não valida senha Incorreta

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Tenho o seguinte jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#email').focus();
    $("#formLogin").validate({
         rules :{
              email: { required: true, email: true},
              senha: { required: true}
        },
        messages:{
              email: { required: 'Campo Requerido.', email: 'Insira Email válido'},
              senha: {required: 'Campo Requerido.'}
        },
       submitHandler: function( form ){  
            var dados = $( form ).serialize();
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "<?php echo base_url();?>entrega/verificarLogin?ajax=true",
              data: dados,
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(data)
              {
                if(data.result == true){
                    window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url();?>entrega";
                }
                else{
                    $('#call-modal').trigger('click');
                }
              }
              });
              return false;
        },

        errorClass: "help-inline",
        errorElement: "span",
        highlight:function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('error');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).parents('.control-group').removeClass('error');
            $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('success');
        }
    });

});
```

E tenho o método VerificarLogin, no CodeIgniter.

```
public function verificarLogin(){

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','valid_email|required|xss_clean|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('senha','Senha','required|xss_clean|trim');
    $ajax = $this->input->get('ajax');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {

        if($ajax == true){
            $json = array('result' => false);
            echo json_encode($json);
        }
        else{

            $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Os dados de acesso estão incorretos.');
            redirect($this->login);
        }
    } 
    else {

        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $senha = $this->input->post('senha');

        $this->load->library('encrypt');   
        $senha = $this->encrypt->sha1($senha);

        $this->db->where('email',$email);
        $this->db->where('senha',$senha);
        $this->db->where('status',1);
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $usuario = $this->db->get('usuario')->row();
        $permissao = $usuario->idPermissao;

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM permissoes WHERE idPermissao = '{$permissao}'";
        $permissao = $this->db->query($sql)->row('permissoes');



        if(count($usuario) > 0){




            $dados = array('nome' => $usuario->nome, 'empresa' =>  $usuario->empresa, 'id' => $usuario->idUsuario, 'idCliente' => $usuario->idCliente, 'permissao' => $usuario->idPermissao, 'permissoes' => $permissao, 'logado' => TRUE);
            $this->session->set_userdata($dados);

            if($ajax == true){
                $json = array('result' => true);
                echo json_encode($json);
            }
            else{
                redirect(base_url().'entrega');
            }


        }
        else{


            if($ajax == true){
                $json = array('result' => false);
                echo json_encode($json);
            }
            else{
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Os dados de acesso estão incorretos.');
                redirect($this->login);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

E o HTML:

```
<form  class="form-vertical" id="formLogin" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url()?>entrega/verificarLogin">
      <?php if($this->session->flashdata('error') != null){?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
              <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('error');?>
           </div>
      <?php }?>
    <div class="control-group normal_text"> <h3><img src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/img/logo-home.png" alt="Logo" /></h3></div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="main_input_box">
                <span class="add-on bg_lg"><i class="icon-user"></i></span><input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="main_input_box">
                <span class="add-on bg_ly"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span><input name="senha" type="password" placeholder="Senha" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions" style="text-align: center">
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-large"/> Logar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Na hora de entrar, entra normal se a senha estiver certa.
Se estiver errada, não vem a mensagem... e não estou conseguindo achar o erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente a validação do login no banco de dados esta sendo feita na condição:

"if(count($usuario) > 0){"

então caso não exista o login e senha digitado, ele entra no else.

Portanto acho que o programa identifica o erro nesse else.

Para saber se está nesse trecho de código, você tem que dar um print dentro dessa condição e fazer um teste com um login que não existe. segue exemplo:

```
if($ajax == true){

  print('a');

  $json = array('result' => false);
  echo json_encode($json);
} else {

  print('b');

  $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Os dados de acesso estão incorretos.');
  redirect($this->login);
}
```

se printar "a" ou "b", você já saberá onde alterar o programa para que seja exibido um erro ao entrar com um login inválido.

Espero ter ajudado.